# Widget not returning view on Future<bool> condition in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Widget not returning view. `isAttrAssignedToProduct` in this method I'm trying to find the assigned attribute in the table if the product exists in the table then return true and the image will be inflated in listview item on the base of true or false. My database returning true or false on condition but the view is not visible.

```
Widget isAttrAssigned(int index){
Future result = isAttrAssignedToProduct(index);
return FutureBuilder(
    future: result,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      result.then((v){
        debugPrint('FUTURE VALE ${v}');
        attr(v);
      });
},);
 Widget attr(bool v){
    return v==true?Container(
      width: 20.0,
      height: 20.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.yellow),
      child: Image.asset('assets/images/right.png'),
    ):Text('df');
  }
```

My Query working fine

```
 Future<bool> isAttrAssignedToProduct(int index) async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> assd=new List<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    try{
      assd= await dbHelper.queryReadGroupAssignedAttribute(productList[index][DatabaseHelper.columnpid]);
      if(assd.length>0){
       // debugPrint('ASSIGNED ATTR PRESENT ${assd.length}');
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }catch(e){
      //debugPrint('ASSIGNED ATTR EXCEPTION ${e}');
      return false;
    }
  }
```

My List Tile

```
ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: height*0.03,right: height*0.03 ),
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProductDetails(pid: productList[index]["pid"],),
                  settings: RouteSettings(name: '/productdetail')),).then((value){
                    setState(() {
                      length=value;
                    });
                    debugPrint('CEHCK BACK FROM DAETAIL $length');
            });
          },
          title: Text(
              '${title}',
              style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'semibold',color: MyColors.colorPrimaryDark,fontSize: 18.0)),
          subtitle: Text(
              'Price \$${price}',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,fontSize: 14.0,fontFamily: 'semibold')),
          trailing:isAttrAssigned( index), //here i'm trying to inflate image
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function `Widget isAttrAssigned` is not returning anything.

If you want to build a widget based on a Future, you can use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

```dart
Widget isAttrAssigned(int index) {
   // maybe you want to cache your result here, to avoid doing a call at each rebuild
   Future result = isAttrAssignedToProduct(index);

   return FutureBuilder(
      future: result
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
     // return widget
   });

}
```

**snapshot.data is your boolean**

```
switch (snapshot.connectionState) { 
case ConnectionState.none: 
return Container(); // empty or show a placeholder 
case ConnectionState.active: 
case ConnectionState.waiting: 
return Text('Loading ...'); 
case ConnectionState.done: 
if (snapshot.hasError) { 
return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'); 
} 
return attr(snapshot.data); 
}
```

Comment: how can i `isAttrAssignedToProduct` value inside `builder`.

Comment: I'm returning view inside the builder but it is showing null.

Comment: sorry did not understand your first question and what is showing null ?

Comment: Inside builder, returning view when result is true but showing `build function must never return null`.

Comment: sure, Please check.

Comment: I need to check inside builder that  result is true or not.

Comment: ok, you don't need reuse `result.then` inside your `FutureBuilder`, the result of your future is available through `AsyncSnapshot`, `snapshot.data` see the doc linked in my comment for more info, and return keyword is not optional in dart except for arrow function, you are still not returning anything, check your analyzer it should complain about it

Comment: `snapshot.data`  i have also tried this, still showing this error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191853/discussion-between-hadrien-lejard-and-farhana).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). Examples in the link. Very easy to use